# Not able to run multiline shell command in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a shell script where I am running a multiline command to fetch version from our UI.

Command I am using is:

```
var=$(curl -k myurl| awk something | sed something)
```

Then I am using the var for further validations.
The above shell is not promoting the correct response. I checked running this in my terminal and command seems fine but this is not working with Jenkins.

Can someone please help me to understand how to solve this issue.

I have gone through multiple posts but no help.

Comment: Bash uses `$` but Groovy uses `$` too. To prevent Groovy from eating your `$` before it gets a chance to get passed to Bash, you need to escape it: `\$`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it is working on your terminal, then it should also work on your Jenkins shell, can you be more brief by sharing the error or difference in response you are getting ,
But anyways as an alternative to this, you can save your shell command in a script file, and execute it using Jenkins.